# How to use django-sslify to force https on my Django+nginx+gunicorn web app, and rely on Cloudflare's new free SSL?

Tags: django, nginx, https, cloudflare, django-sslify

## Intro

[Cloudflare's providing SSL for free](http://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-universal-ssl/) now, and I would be a fool to not take advantage of this on my site, and a downright dickhead to break everything in the process of trying to.

I can code apps just fine, but when it comes to setting up or configuring https/nginx/gunicorn/etc/idon'tknowtheterminology, I know barely enough to follow Googled instructions.

## Question

I would like to use django-sslify to force https on my Django web app. How may I achieve this <strike>without upsetting the balance in my life</strike>, given the following known facts?

## Known facts

1. I'm using Django 1.7, running on a DigitalOcean server hooked up
   to a (free) Cloudflare DNS. Django is fitted (served?) with nginx
   and gunicorn. Basically followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn) to get it all set up.
2. Accessing my website currently defaults to a regular http://example.com header.
3. Manually accessing https://example.com works with
   the green lock and all, but this breaks all form submissions with
   the error "(403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.".
4. In my Cloudflare site settings, the domain is currently configured to "Flexible SSL".
5. Trying to use django-sslify with my existing setup totally breaks everything, and the browser is unable to return a response.
6. [This info nugget](https://github.com/rdegges/django-sslify/issues/2) tells me that I should use the "Full SSL" configuration setting when using django-sslify with Cloudflare's SSL.
7. Cause for hesitation found [here](https://mikecoutermarsh.com/adding-ssl-to-heroku-with-cloudflare/) where it is mentioned that a $20/mo Pro Cloudflare account is needed to handle SSL termination. So I really don't want to screw this up :/
8. There was only 1 mention of "http" or "https" anywhere in my nginx and gunicorn configuration, specifically in my nginx config:

> `location / {`
>         `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;     ...       }`

## Ok I think that's all I have

Also, my server is providing an Django Rest Framework api for a Phonegap app, does that need to be taken in to consideration? If I need to provide addtional information do let me know and I'll get back to you. Thank you for taking a look at this! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CloudFlare allows you to enable specific [page rules](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules), one of which is to force SSL (by [doing a hard redirect](http://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-pagerules-url-forwarding/)). This is a great thing to use *in addition to* `django-sslify` or `django-secure`

---

In addition to setting up your SSL redirect, you also need to tell Django to handle secure requests. Luckily, [Django provides a decent guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/security/#ssl-https) for doing this, but there *are a few things* that it doesn't mention but I've had to do with nginx.

In your Django settings, you need to tell Django how to detect a secure request

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL', 'https')
```

In your nginx configuration you need to set up the `X-Forwarded-Protocol` header (and the `X-Forwarded-For`/`X-Scheme` headers are also useful).

```
proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

You also need to proxy the `Host` header down, so Django is able to read the correct host and port, which is used in generating absolute urls and CSRF, among other things.

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

Note that I used the `$http_host` variable instead of `$host` or `$host:$server_port`. This will ensure that Django will still respect CSRF requests on non-standard ports, while still giving you the correct absolute urls.

As with most things related to nginx and gunicorn, YMMV and it gets easier after you do it a few times.

Comment: This answer gives me excellent direction to pursue, thank you!

Comment: Another question - How would SSL Certificates fit in here?

Comment: @gx14 CloudFlare's Flexible SSL works well for most people, unless you want Full SSL you aren't going to need to purchase certificates and [configure nginx](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-nginx.htm) to use them.